# How can I extend Atom's HTML grammar to syntax highlight custom javascript tag

Tags: regex, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

I am creating custom package (basically an extended HTML Syntax Highlighting) and I need Atom to understand that `{{#script}}` is the same as `<script>` and `{{/script}}` is `</script>` in order for it to highlight javascript code enclosed on those custom tags.

I think it could be done in this section of the .cson file but not totally sure. Can you help? If this is the right block what should the modified version look like? What regex should I use? Many thanks!

```
{
    'begin': '(?:^\\s+)?(<)((?i:script))\\b(?![^>]*/>)'
    'beginCaptures':
      '1':
        'name': 'punctuation.definition.tag.html'
      '2':
        'name': 'entity.name.tag.script.html'
    'end': '(?<=</(script|SCRIPT))(>)(?:\\s*\\n)?'
    'endCaptures':
      '2':
        'name': 'punctuation.definition.tag.html'
    'contentName': 'source.js.embedded.html'
    'patterns': [
      {
        'include': '#tag-stuff'
      }
      {
        'begin': '(?<!</(?:script|SCRIPT))(>)'
        'captures':
          '1':
            'name': 'punctuation.definition.tag.html'
          '2':
            'name': 'entity.name.tag.script.html'
        'end': '(</)((?i:script))'
        'patterns': [
          {
            'include': 'source.js'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you want to modify this to match both `<script>` and `{{#script}}`, or create a new one for `{{#script}}`? Can there be `{{#script/}}` = `<script/>`?

Comment: @wiktor Matching both at the same time would be ideal

Comment: I tried that and failed, sorry.